# What Port Does AWS S3 Use?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-security-group

I have a question because of error which I Faced due to configs some other person made in aws :

Short Question is what port Does **AWS S3** use to communicate to ec2-instance ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

S3 supported protocols are

- HTTP (**port 80**) connection
- HTTPS (**port 443**) connection

Its does not use different protocol / port wether it communicates with EC2 instance or non-AWS instance

Comment: Thanks for Confirming

Comment: I found in aws sdk 1.1, there is way to set the proxyport in clientconfiguration? then what port does it refer to in this case?